# Python: expand list of strings by adding n elements for each original element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list of strings:

```
l1 = ['one','two','three']
```

I want to obtain a list that has, say, these same elements repeated `n` times. If `n=3` I'd get:

```
l2 = ['one','one','one','two','two','two','three','three','three']
```

What I am trying is this:

```
l2 = [3*i for i in l1]
```

But what I obtain is this:

```
l2 = ['oneoneone','twotwotwo','threethreethree']
```

If I try this:

```
l2 = [3*(str(i)+",") for i in l1]
```

I obtain:

```
l2 = ['one,one,one','two,two,two','three,three,three']
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Adding a `','` does not evaluate as separate list elements, it's just a string with a comma character…

Comment: If you're doing code golf you could get away with `sorted(l1*3,key=l1.index)` in this example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 l2 = [j for i in l1  for j in 3*[i]]
```

This gives:

```
 ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three']
```

This is equivalent to:

```
l2 = []
for i in l1:
    for j in 3*[i]:
       l2.append(j)
```

Note that `3*[i]` creates a list with 3 repeated elements (e.g. `['one', one', 'one']`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use itertools to transform a list of list into a list (in a fast way) :

```py
from itertools import chain
l1 = ['one','two','third']
l2 = list(chain.from_iterable([[e]*3 for e in l1]))
# l2 = ['one','one','one','two','two','two','three','three','three']
```

so you can define a function that repeat elements like this :

```py
def repeat_elements(l, n)
    return list(chain.from_iterable([[e]*n for e in l]))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use pure list comprehension

```
 [myList[i//n] for i in range(n*len(myList))]
```

**Explanation:**

if original list has k elements, repetition factor is n
=> total number of items in final list: n*k

To map range n*k to k elements, Divide by n. Remember integer divison

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution. Just a couple of things: use the integer division operator (`//`) rather than the regular division one (`/`). Also, it's redundant to include the zero as the first argument passed to `range()` if you're not passing the three possible arguments at once. Just change it to `range(n*len(myList))`

Comment: Thanks @revliscano. I have done the suggested edits

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `map` with `sum`

```
print(list(sum(map(lambda x: [x] * 3, l1), [])))
```

Output

```
['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three']
```